# What is the correct format about this class name?

Tags: php, html, font-awesome, yii2-advanced-app

I would like to know the correct format about this class Name

```
field($model, 'status')->widget(AwesomeCheckbox::classname()) ?>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Comment: If you are looking what does this code do: Call function `field` with model and attribute, return some object with method `widget` that requires class name that must be processed.

Comment: This class   `classname()`, I need an example about what I have to put in this class  `classname()` Thank you for helping me.

Comment: for example like this  `widget(AwesomeCheckbox::(new \yii\db\Query()) `    I need to call datas from the database using a class

Comment: `$form->field($model, 'consumido')->widget(AwesomeCheckbox::map(Personas::find()->all(), 'idPersona', 'desPersona')) ?> ` I have tried this but it does not work